# Raspberry Pi completely running without a PC (SSH), a keyboard or a monitor

Tags: pi-3, headless

I run a script through the terminal created via Bitvise SSH Client that collects data with an accelerometer.

Now I was wondering if it's possible to completely shut down the terminal and connection to the Raspberry Pi from the PC while still having the script running on the Raspberry Pi itself. So when I access the Raspberry Pi again the script would still be running.

You might wonder if I need to interact with the script or if I just want to kick it off and then it does stuff on its own. Well to begin with I just want to kick it off.

Comment: can a question be a duplicate of another site?
https://superuser.com/questions/178587/how-do-i-detach-a-process-from-terminal-entirely

Comment: Using `setsid this_is_my_command` works perfectly fine!

Answer (score 1):

Look into the `screen` command.
https://www.rackaid.com/blog/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/

If the device is near your PC, you don't even need SSH, just connect it by serial. You won't need the to the `screen` trick, and you can use Putty.